# Creating a docker swarm cluster in Vagrant

Tags: ubuntu, vagrant, virtual-machine, docker-swarm

I'm trying to create a swarm cluster of diffferent ubuntu VMs running in Vagrant.
These have docker enabled via the vagrant file that boots them. Of the three VM's I started the swarm cluster on one machine in the following way

```
docker pull swarm
docker run --rm swarm create
```

This returned a unique cluster_id. ON another docker enabled vm, I performed the following steps

1. Stop the docker daemon

   `sudo service docker stop`
2. Start the daemon with -H flag

   `sudo  docker -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2375 -d`

This gives the following

```
    INFO[0000] +job init_networkdriver()
    INFO[0000] +job serveapi(tcp://0.0.0.0:2375)
    INFO[0000] Listening for HTTP on tcp (0.0.0.0:2375)
    INFO[0000] /!\ DON'T BIND ON ANY IP ADDRESS WITHOUT setting -tlsverify IF        YOU DON'T KNOW WHAT YOU'RE DOING /!\
    INFO[0000] -job init_networkdriver() = OK (0)
    INFO[0000] Loading containers: start.

    INFO[0000] Loading containers: done.
    INFO[0000] docker daemon: 1.6.2 7c8fca2; execdriver: native-graphdriver:aufs
    INFO[0000] +job acceptconnections()
    INFO[0000] -job acceptconnections() = OK (0)
    INFO[0000] Daemon has completed initialization
```

After this I start another session with this node and want to run  run the following command:

```
sudo docker run -d swarm join --addr=<node_ip:2375> token://<cluster_id>
```

What is the node ip in this case? Using arp -an on this VM gives me three IP's which one is the one that is accessible

Comment: can you show error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As show [swarm/discovery](https://docs.docker.com/swarm/discovery/) in comment:

```
# on each of your nodes, start the swarm agent
#  <node_ip> doesn't have to be public (eg. 192.168.0.X),
#  as long as the swarm manager can access it.
$ swarm join --addr=<node_ip:2375> token://<cluster_id>
```

**node_ip** it's the ip address of the new node of the cluster.